Automatic deletion of the source branch after merging in Bitbucket

The ui shows the process of merging the admin_assessment branch into the main development branch. However, the issue is that even if I don’t select the "Close source branch" option, the branch still gets deleted after clicking the merge button in Bitbucket. How can I prevent this? Please help.
I tried merging the admin_assessment branch into the main development branch in Bitbucket. Before merging, I ensured that the "Close source branch" option was not selected, as I wanted the source branch to remain after the merge. However, despite not selecting that option, the source branch was automatically deleted after I clicked the merge button. I was expecting the source branch to remain intact after the merge, but that did not happen.

My understanding is "Close" is the same as "Delete", and if you leave it unchecked, the source branch should not be deleted. If it is getting deleted as you described, then either that is a bug (which would be surprising since everyone would be complaining about it), or, perhaps there is another global setting somewhere that is overriding your selection, or perhaps another global process that is cleaning up old and/or merged branches.

Regardless of why it happened, after a regular merge, you can just look at the history of dev and recreate the branch if you still need it. Right after the PR is completed git log dev^2 would be the same as git log Admin_Assessment. If other PRs have completed since then you can just inspect the history to find the correct merge commit and take the second parent of that. The fact that it's so easy to re-create a branch after it's merged, is the reason most people usually prefer to delete branches as soon as they're merged. (A time to not delete is if merging into multiple branches.)
